# Are these three 'stormy' sentences synonyms?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

Are ”there’s a storm coming” and ”there’s a storm approaching” a synonym of ”there’s a storm brewing”?

If they are, which one sounds more natural and you use frequently?

Comment: All three are idiomatic and in quite common usage—and mean the same thing. Which you choose probably depends on how dramatic you want to be. For the most dramatic effect, I'd choose *brewing*, but that is just one person's opinion. Use what you feel comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Brewing, as in "see what the weather is brewing up for the weekend" sounds more like a a warning or alert.

Comment: Some people use "storm brewing" to imply that the storm has not yet fully formed anywhere, but will soon be here.  Both "coming" and "approaching" suggest that the storm already exists, and its path will bring it here.

Comment: _Coming_ and _approaching_ mean the same thing. _Brewing_, however, is a cooking metaphor, and does not refer to motion toward the speaker like _come_ and _approach_ do.

Comment: Ah yes, but in Game of Thrones they said: Winter is coming. It wouldn't have had any punch if they had said approaching. Funny, huh? And thank goodness, the writers did not talking about winter brewing. [yes, that's a joke]

Answer (score 1):

All the phrases (preferable 1st and 2nd) can be interchanged for colloquial usage, yet there are subtle differences.

1. A storm *coming* means it is right about the happen. On your doorstep.
2. A storm *approaching* to an extent can be understood as less urgent.
3. A storm *brewing* implies it has not yet acquired its shape/intensity.

All of them are natural depending on the context. I am more of a laid back person so I prefer "a storm coming" (when I finally take note of it).